# Where is the monaco-editor autocompletion located?

Tags: javascript, typescript, monaco-editor

I'm creating a PromQL language support for monaco-editor and I found that the languages definition are located in this repository :
https://github.com/microsoft/monaco-languages

But I don't manage to find where are located the autocompletion definitions for these languages.

I already know how to add some custom completion.

What I want to know now is **where the builtin completion is located ?**

**Edit**:
I found that some languages have some specific repositories which contains well some completion items, like:

- typescript https://github.com/microsoft/monaco-typescript
- css https://github.com/microsoft/monaco-css
- ...

Now what about the other languages, like Java, Python ... ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Asked the question to monaco-editor repository directly.

Main answer :

> I believe Monaco only comes with support for JavaScript/TypeScript,
>   CSS, JSON, and HTML by default and that is why those monaco-abc
>   repositories exist. There is no code completion for other languages
>   such as Java and Python by default.

So I created a separate repository https://github.com/celian-garcia/monaco-languages-promql including enough documentation to be easily integrated with minimum of code.

More details here: https://github.com/microsoft/monaco-editor/issues/1672