# Url Editor Like Postman Using Monaco Editor

Tags: angular, typescript, postman, monaco-editor

How can I make a custom editor using "Monaco Editor" to write URL in the text box and show the internal variable when enter character '{' and change color for this variable

I want to build it using angular, for example:

[image: postman editor url]

Comment: That's not a good question we can help with. Please read [how-to-ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to get an idea what is necessary to ask a question that gets enough attention.

Answer (score 0):

Are you asking about how to customize the Monaco editor autocomplete feature?

Maybe these links will help:

https://microsoft.github.io/monaco-editor/api/modules/monaco.languages.html

[Where is the monaco-editor autocompletion located?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57921084/where-is-the-monaco-editor-autocompletion-located)

[monaco editor based namespace auto complete](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51536492/monaco-editor-based-namespace-auto-complete)